# ng-bootstrap pagination not able to overwrite 'next', 'previous' via i18n

Tags: angular, pagination, ng-bootstrap

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/overview states that we can:

> use the Angular i18n API as all labels are translated. For instance you could replace the default '«' (previous arrow) with the 'Prev' text by providing a different translation for the ngb.pagination.previous key in your i18n file

I am using angular.io version 6 with ng-bootstrap 4.2.1. I have put

```
"ngb": {
    "pagination": {
        "first": "erster",
        "previous": "vorhergehender",
        "next": "nächster",
        "last": "letzter",
        "first-aria": "erste Seite",
        "previous-aria": "vorhergehende Seite",
        "next-aria": "nächste Seite",
        "last-aria": "letzte Seite"
    }
},
```

into my de.json file but this does not work. It still shows the english default values. In the browser-console I can see that the ngb.pagination.first et al. strings are delvered but the pagination component does not change the default text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ng-bootstrap uses the standard Angular i18n mechanism as described in https://angular.io/guide/i18n, which is not based on JSON files. It doesn't use the external library that you're using for i18n (whatever that can be). Read the end of the guide to know how to use custom templates.

Comment: Thank you @jb-nizet. That perfectly explains my issue!